# Server Build Error Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have a basic Codename One subscription, from my side it's ok my code is compiling fine, the Simulator is working fine as well, but the Codename One Server is getting Build Error, I tried a few times but still not working, there is the build error log, but it's too long for posting it here, what should I do?

Comment: There are web services like "pastebin.com" (or similar ones) in which you can paste the log and then get a public link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build errors can occur for many reasons which is why the error links to an error log that includes the full details on why the server failed to build your app. The log can be hard to interpret sometimes so if this isn't clear you can do one of the following:

- Ask here - sometimes you get voted down/moderated though if you are asking something obvious/partial. There is also limits on long log files
- Ask in the discussion forum
- Ask our support engineer in the website chat widget